# Higher solutions to Pell's equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $nm$ be the product of the natural numbers $n$ and $m$.
Let $y(1)$ be the lowest solution for certain $d$ to Pell’s equation $x^2-dy^2=1$, and let $y(n)$ be the $n$’th lowest solution.

I note for some limited examples of the constant $d$ that $y(nm)$ contains the same prime factors as $y(n)*y(m) $. (In addition $y(nm)$ also contains one or two new primes).

It this right in general and is it obvious to you?

$y(n)$ is of the form $a^n-b^n$ so it is not completely trivial.

Comment: This may be related to the concept of "divisibility sequences".

Comment: It is trivial - or obvious - for the relations between $y(n), y(n^2), y(n^4)$ and $y(n^8)$ etc.,  since $y(n)=2x(n-1)*y(n-1) $ and $y(n-1)=2x(n-2)*y(n-2) $ etc., derived from the fact that   $x^2-dy^2=1 $ implies $(2x^2-1)^2-d(2xy)^2$.

Comment: I note from Wikipedia that sequences of this kind are divisibility sequences, although my sequence is actually made up of the terms $(a^n-b^n)/c$

Answer (score 2):

Things like this are well-known (though I can't guarantee precisely what you've found is known, since your description is somewhat vague). For example, see [this paper about properties of Pell numbers](http://tony.reix.free.fr/Mersenne/PropertiesOfPellNumbers.pdf) — there are many, many properties which could be contributing to what you've observed.